# JNLP cert issue for jogl. signed jars and now java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, certificate, jnlp, jogl

Java has changed their security policy so we could no longer self sign our app. Then they changed it so any libraries we called couldnt be self signed so we used our certificate auth cert to sign those too, but when I try to run our jnlp I get the following and can't find which line or even which file the error is for.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebaseEx(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: you need to insert a number not an empty string

Comment: what? where? what line? what file?

Comment: Of course in your code maybe at home.

Comment: my code did not change. all I did was sign the libraries that we call and all of a sudden it stops working. from the error message it seems the error is somewhere in one of the manifest files, but it doesnt say which one or what line the error is on and I can't find it.

Comment: try to post the code how gives you the error

Comment: I dont get the error in my ide. I only get the error after signing the libraries I call with our certificate. So I cant debug the code.